Upload .tar.gz to s3 bucket using presigned url with node.js
I am facing an issue uploading a .tar.gz file to an s3 bucket using a presinged URL.
If I upload any other file then it works without any error but with .tar.gz it does not give any error and does not upload the file too.
Below is the sample code.
  const tarFile = '/tmp/some.tar.gz';
  const data = fs.readFileSync(tarFile);

  const req = https.request(
    url,
    {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Content-Length': new Blob([data]).size,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-gzip',
        'Content-Encoding': 'gzip',
      },
    },
    (res) => {
      let responseBody = '';
      res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        responseBody += chunk;
      });
      res.on('end', () => {
        console.log({ responseBody });
      });
    }
  );
  req.on('error', (err) => {
    reject(err);
  });
  req.write(data);
  req.end();


I might be offbase here, but I don't think you want Content-Encoding: gzip.  That tells the other end "what I want to send you is INSIDE the gzipped content herein".  The other end is then supposed to UNZIP it for use.  Do you have "some.tar" in your bucket?  I think you should delete the "Content-Encoding" header.

There is nothing in the bucket. We are creating a pre-signed URL and providing that to another service to upload the content.
If the key length is more than 82 chars then it fails to upload the .tar.gz
It sounds weird but that is happening.

There is probably something going on with code not shown.  A small minimal reproducible example of creating a tar.gz file, a presigned URL, and using this code to upload it to S3 with a large key all works.
